# How to open a new "NewForm.aspx" after an item is being saved? SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, newform

I have a list named `Parent`. After I create and save an item I want to be redirected to the `NewForm` of that list (`Parent`) again, to create another item.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `Source` query string parameter.

For the URL such as `NewForm.aspx?Source=NewForm.aspx`

Comment: Where should I put this link and how?

Comment: One way is to add a Content Editor Webpart in add a hyper link.. Or you can use JavaScript to dynamically set this URL to the New Item link

Comment: Due I am new to SharePoint development can you tell me how javascript would like look or how to add that hyperlink in content editor?

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps:

1) Download SharePoint Designer( same version as your sharepoint).
2) Download the Jquery file from internet and save it in Style library copy its path.
3) Open your site and navigate to NewForm.aspx of the Parent list.
4) You will see all XSLT and JS files mentioned there.
5) Refer your jquery inside contentplaceholder tag like this 
6) Now open other script tag in next line

```
<script type=text/js> 
function PreSaveAction(){
$window.location= "(your Newform location)";
return true;
}
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Instead of putting it in NewForm.aspx in Designer, Can I edit the default new form of my list and add a script editor there?

Comment: I wouldn't use that code. It redirects to the new URL even if the validation of the item fails and is therefore never saved.

Comment: @DanielStölzner however the code it is not working for me in both ways

Comment: if you need to check validation then there are many other stuffs which can be taken into account before submitting the form. I gave the code to navigate nothing more was asked.You can edit the Save button xslt in the designer and try to navigate to your desired page.

Comment: This will not work.